# Images with absolute positions not working with overlay text

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position

I'm trying to place an overlay text when hovered over an image but it's not working since the image is already in position absolute, so I can't use relative positioning. I tried to wrap them in a div but the image disappears and shifts from original location. Here's my code and screenshots:

```
<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
                    <img src="assets/img/Carrot-Mutabal.jpg" class="image-1 shadow-lg img-fluid">
                    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                        <p class="content-text">This is a short description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <img src="assets/img/Monk's-Mutabal.jpg" class="image-2 shadow-lg ">
                <img src="assets/img/Prawn-Crescents.jpg" class="image-3 shadow-lg ">
                <img src="assets/img/Noura's-Vine-Leaves.jpg" class="image-4 shadow-lg ">
            </div>
    .image-2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3%;
    left: 4%;
    width: 30%;
}
.image-3{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 20%;
}
.image-4{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    width: 30%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .content-overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 99%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.image-1{
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 2%;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 35%;
    }
.content:hover .content-overlay{
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-details{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-details p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.fadeIn-bottom{
  top: 80%;
}
```

How I display the images in absolute

[image]

Edit: As CBroe suggested positioning the wrapper instead of div worked.

Comment: Position the wrapping div elements, instead of the images …?

Comment: well i feel like an idiot. been at this for hours and now it works perfectly. I thank you!